# How to include part of another git repository using git subtree and merge updates in both directions

Tags: git, github, git-merge, git-subtree

I have two git repositories show below. The first is structured like a typical python project.

```
foo_repo/
    .git/
    setup.py
    foo/
         __init__.py
         some_code.py
    tests/

bar/
    .git/
```

I would like to include the `foo_repo/foo/` directory in `bar/` as a subtree and I want to be able to merge updates to `foo_repo/foo/some_code.py` both from the foo_repo repository to bar and vice versa.

The initial setup isn't too bad.  From the `foo/` directory I use:

```
git subtree --prefix=foo/ split -b export
```

Then I have a new branch in foo_repo with only the contents of the `foo_repo/foo/` directory.  To bring this into bar, I just go to the `bar/` directory and:

```
git subtree --prefix=foo/ add ../foo_repo/.git export
```

Now that I'm all set up, I'd like to do some code development and keep `foo/` up to date in both repos.  Pushing from bar I think I have figured out.  From `bar/` directory:

```
touch foo/more_code.py
git add foo/more_code.py
git commit -m "more code"
git subtree --prefix=foo/ push ../foo_repo/.git export
```

Then from the `foo_repo/` directory:

```
git checkout master
git subtree --prefix=foo/ merge export
```

Merging the other way is where I'm stuck.  From `foo_repo/`:

```
git checkout master
touch foo/yet_more_code.py
git add foo/yet_more_code.py
git commit -m "yet more code"
???
```

Where the `???` is a command that merges the `foo/` directory with the `export` branch. Then from `bar/`:

```
git subtree --prefix=foo/ pull ../foo_repo/.git export
```

So I'm basically looking for the line that goes in the `???` spot, or a different workflow that does the same thing.  I've tried repeating `git subtree --prefix=foo/ split -b export_foo` by that doesn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you split again `foo/` the new commits created for this subtree will be created on top of the old commits already existing in `export`, including the merges that are needed for such:

```
git subtree --prefix=foo/ split
```

Notice that if using the `-b` option the branch should not exist previuosly, so you might need to create a new branch or later force it to change.

Comment: This fails for everything other than trivial merges when I do the finally `git subtree pull`. It even fails for fast forward merges. Somehow the subtree history seems to have been lost in the `bar` repository.